# Installing Spring-XD on Hortonworks HDP

Tags: redhat, yum, hortonworks-data-platform, spring-xd

I'm trying to install Spring-XD on the Hortonworks HDP Sandbox (VM Virtualbox running Red Hat).

According to the Spring-XD  documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.M6/reference/html/#redhatcentos-installation), you can "install Spring XD using homebrew on OSX and yum on RedHat/CentOS."

I've tried `yum search spring` and with other spelling permutations, but get no matches.

Can anyone explain how to install spring-xd in this environment, whether via yum or other means?